# Отбросить строки повторяющие по одной колонке

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как-то средствами T-SQL выполнить следующее преобразование:

Исходная таблица:

| RN | WorkItemID | VERSION | DATE | USER | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 25.11.22 | Олег | 1 |
| 2 | 123 | 2 | 25.11.22 | Максим | 2 |
| 3 | 123 | 3 | 25.11.22 | Олег | 5 |
| 4 | 123 | 4 | 25.11.22 | Олег | 5 |
| 5 | 123 | 5 | 25.11.22 | Максим | 5 |
| 6 | 123 | 6 | 25.11.22 | Максим | 8 |
| 7 | 123 | 7 | 25.11.22 | Олег | 8 |

Результат:

| RN | WorkItemID | VERSION | DATE | USER | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 25.11.22 | Олег | 1 |
| 2 | 123 | 2 | 25.11.22 | Максим | 2 |
| 3 | 123 | 3 | 25.11.22 | Олег | 5 |
| 6 | 123 | 6 | 25.11.22 | Максим | 8 |

Исходная таблица формируется с помощью следующего запроса:

```sql
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wir.[WorkItemId], DATEFROMPARTS(d.[Year], d.[MonthOfYear], d.[DayOfMonth]) ASC) AS [RN]
    , wir.[WorkItemId] AS [Идентификатор рабочего элемента]
    , u.[UserName] AS [Сотрудник]
    , p.[ProjectName] AS [Проект]
    , DATEFROMPARTS(d.[Year], d.[MonthOfYear], d.[DayOfMonth]) AS [Дата]
    , COALESCE(wir.[CompletedWork], 0)
FROM [AnalyticsModel].[vw_WorkItemRevision] AS wir
JOIN [AnalyticsModel].[vw_User] AS u
    ON wir.[ChangedByUserSK] = u.[UserSK]
JOIN [AnalyticsModel].[vw_Project] AS p
    ON wir.[ProjectSK] = p.[ProjectSK]
JOIN [AnalyticsModel].[tbl_Date] AS d
    ON wir.[ChangedDateSK] = d.[DateSK]
```

Comment: вы словами логику этого преобразования не хотите описать?

Comment: можно окошками сравнить значение юзера в текущей и предыдущей строке, а потом отфильтровать совпадающие

Comment: Типовая задача "выбор одной записи из группы по критерию". Как я вижу, группа - по значению VALUE, а критерий - минимальное RN либо VERSION.